# How to change php 5.2 mhash codes to php5.3 hash

Tags: php, hash, md5, php-5.2

Friends my php 5.2 codes am keeping my password like this

```
echo '<br>'.base64_encode(mhash(MHASH_MD5,'test'));
result  CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==
```

In php 5.3 mhash extension is obsoleted by Hash like I saw in there documentation. So I tried like this. But its giving wrong result.

```
echo '<br>'.base64_encode(hash(MD5,'test'));
result MDk4ZjZiY2Q0NjIxZDM3M2NhZGU0ZTgzMjYyN2I0ZjY=
```

Please help me to convert my 5.2 mhash codes to 5.3.

Thanks

Comment: `bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $test))` if you do this what will be the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, they are the same, only in a different format.
The first one is binary data, while the second one is hexadecimal.
You can convert the first one to the second using this function:

```
$second_hash = bin2hex ($first_hash);
```

Or the other way around:

```
$first_hash = hex2bin ($second_hash);
```

### Update

Add this function:

```
define('HEX2BIN_WS', " \t\n\r");

function hex2bin($hex_string) {
    $pos = 0;
    $result = '';
    while ($pos < strlen($hex_string)) {
      if (strpos(HEX2BIN_WS, $hex_string{$pos}) !== FALSE) {
        $pos++;
      } else {
        $code = hexdec(substr($hex_string, $pos, 2));
        $pos = $pos + 2;
        $result .= chr($code); 
      }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen I just edited my post. I tried with hex2bin. but its showing Call to undefined function hex2bin()

Comment: My bad, hex2bin() is a new function in PHP 5.4; I've added a custom one to my post

Comment: If your PHP doesn't have hex2bin(), you can create it as follows:

    if (!function_exists('hex2bin')) { function hex2bin($hex) { return pack('H*', $hex); }

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update obsolete mhash() method to hash_hmac() method using sha1, simply replace :

```
mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $data, $key)
```

into

```
hash_hmac('sha1', $data,$key,true)
```

In my context i was faced to old piece of code

```
base64_encode(mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $data, $key));
```

which i replaced by

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data,$key,true));
```

I hope it could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
mhash(MHASH_MD5, 'FOOBAR'); // what you have
pack('H*', hash(MD5, 'FOOBAR')) // what you accepted
pack('H*', md5('FOOBAR')); // ...
md5('FOOBAR', true); // what you could/should have used
```

I know this question is rather old but today I had the same problem. Based on this post I was able to find a shorter and I guess more performant way which is worth sharing in my opinion.